# Editing and validating complex model in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have an application utilizing EntityFramework with SQL2008. I'm using DB-first approach. Below shows two entities I have problem with :

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/modelfj.jpg/

**part of the Employee Edit.cshtml**

```
<div class="client_row">
    <label class="client_label">
        FirstName</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "client_edit" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
</div>
<div class="client_row">
    <label class="client_label">
        LastName</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "client_edit" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</div>

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Account)

<div class="client_row">
    <span class="client_hr"></span>
    <label class="client_label">
        Email</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "client_edit" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
</div>
```

**Account Editor file (user by EditorFor )**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccountID)
<div class="client_row">
    <label class="client_label">
        Login</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Login, new { @class = "client_edit" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Login)
</div>
<div class="client_row">
    <label class="client_label">
        Password</label>
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "client_edit password1" })
```

**My partial Account file used for validation**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Account_Validation))]
public partial class Account
{
}
[Bind(Exclude = "AccountID")]
public class Account_Validation
{
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsLoginAvailable", "Validation")]
    [Display(Name="Login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name="Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
</div>
```

When I try to create an employee everything works fine. I'm able to insert into Employee table and to Account table. I've implemented standard remote validation (using data annotations) to check for login name availability.

Problem starts when I'm trying to edit employee. Validation wouldn't allow me to do that, as its saying the login is already taken. Well, that's true, but I don't want to change it. Can you guys tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your existing DataAnnotations on your model?

Comment: Sure, I just added code samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is create a ViewModel for Add Employee and Edit Employee, have them both inherit from a base viewmodel

It's a similar situation to create account and login, just because you are dealing with the same entity doesn't mean you should use the same validation logic.

Comment: An example would come in handy. If I inherit from base class ( Employee from edmx model ) I already have the Account reference, right ? so How do I make different ViewModels for EntityFramework model - one for Create and other for Edit action ?

Comment: No your viewmodel would be a DTO (Data Transfer Object) that doesn't have any relationship to your domain object (Employee). If you ignore the inheritance for a moment and just focus on the idea that you create a new class for form, that way you can have the validation logic vary from form to form. As a side note I'd also recommend you look at fluentvalidation.